# Azure App Service with native Tomcat - how to modify tomcat-users.xml?

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Service running native, non-marketplace Tomcat.  I want to be able to restart specific webapps, instead of restarting the whole Tomcat/app service.

GUI Tomcat Manager is not available, so I figure I could do it via command line.  To get access to it, I need to modify tomcat-users.xml, but it's in the system folders, and is not editable.

How can I specify my tomcat users?  There is already a way to use web.config in wwwroot folder to override JVM options and to change other Tomcat settings, so maybe there is a way to specify tomcat users as well?